# Why am I experiencing such slow fetchmany() performance with sqlite3 in python?

Tags: python, sql, performance, sqlite

I have two tables with ~9 to 12million records that I am joining on their primary key for all columns (30 columns each). I then load 100,000 (have also tried 1,000, 10,000 etc) rows into memory at a time to process it in chunks.

It takes ~9 seconds in SQL for this query:

9477056 rows returned in 9646ms from: SELECT A.*, B.* FROM 'tableA_2019-12-08' A JOIN 'tableB_2019-12-08' B USING(Symbol);

But I am seeing 250-300 seconds in python.

Here's the python code:

````
myQuery = "SELECT {} FROM '{}' A JOIN '{}' B USING(Symbol)".format(ColumnsToSelect,table1_name,table2_name)
c.execute(myQuery)
nr = 0
while c.fetchmany(100000) != []: # this will break when no more rows will be returned i.e end of table
    nr+=1
    print(nr)
    results = c.fetchmany(100000)
    #code to process results goes here but I commented it out to test the fetchmany speed```

Does anyone know why this is happening?

Edit: Tried changing it to this but I have the same issue, taking 250 seconds:

```DataProcessed = False
    start_time_diffgen = time.time()
    while DataProcessed is not True: # this will break when no more rows will be returned i.e end of table
        result = c.fetchmany(1000000)
        nr+=1
        if result == []:
            DataProcessed = True```
````

Comment: You're calling `fetchmany()` in the while statement without assigning the results to a variable.  This is essentially discarding 100,000 rows, then storing the next 100,000 rows in `results`, then discarding the next 100,000 rows, ...

Comment: Printing is never a good test of execution speed/efficiency.  Instead you're just testing the speed of printing to the console.  This can vary wildly depending on text output buffering, development environment, etc.

Comment: thanks, I tried changing my code (see main post edit) then but it's the same amount of time taken about 252 seconds which seems excessive. Is this code still looking wrong?